# Building wxpython exe using PyInstaller

Tags: python, module, matplotlib, wxpython, pyinstaller

I am trying to build an exe using PyInstaller (with Python 2.7) and have been stumped.  My python code uses the modules wx, matplotlib, basemap (a part of matplotlib), and pylab.  There are others, but these seem to be the main ones.

I have installed PyInstaller and then i did:

```
python pyinstaller.py C:/Python27/Convertthisfile.py
```

It goes through the whole process, but when i try to run the final executable, it comes up with the error:

"No module named PyQt4.QtCore"

I have installed PyQt GPL 4.9.1 for Python 2.7.  However, I have no idea where PyQt is even being used in my code.  I don't specify it anywhere that i know of.

Anyone have any thoughts?  Nothing I do seems to work.  I have even tried the GUI2EXE.py -- i can't get py2exe, pyinstaller, or cx_freeze to work.

HELP!

I have added my code below to hopefully help.  To answer the comments, yes, my code is located in C:\Python27.  I have no problem "building" it with pyinstaller, but the above error comes up when i try to run the given executable.  I have searched the code and do not see any use of PyQt4.

When i run cx_freeze, i have issues with the basemap data files -- they do not seem to be included in the ".zip" when i build it.  Also, none of my modules seem to get included either.

Here is what i import for my code (some of these functions are my own -- mainly the last ones listed).

```
import wx
import time
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import FigureCanvasWx as FigureCanvas
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from datetime import datetime
import wx.calendar as cal
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
from pylab import *
from decimal import *
import adodbapi
import annote_new
import cPickle as pickle
import calc_dist
import Game_Score
import Calculate_Distance
import Duplicate_Finder
import copy
```

Hopefully this clears things up?

Comment: grep?  not sure i understand...

Comment: search your code :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep#Usage_as_a_verb

Comment: How exactly does cx_Freeze fail? I use it all the time without problems.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this.  I've got wx (2.9.3), matplotlib (1.1.0) and PyQt (4.9.4) all installed on my system and I used pyinstaller (2.0) to build an executable, which ran without error.  Is the Python script you're trying to build an executable for *really* located in `C:\Python27`?

Comment: cx_freeze works well with some adjustments